# Heroku file storage with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, heroku, carrierwave, sidekiq

I have a simple setup going for an API i'm building in rails.

A zip is uploaded via a POST, and I take the file, store it in `rails.root/tmp` using carrierwave and then background an s3 upload with sidekiq.

the reason i store the file temporarily is because i can't send a complex object to sidekiq, so i store it and send the id, and let sidekiq find it and do work with it, then delete the file once it's done.

the problem is that once it's time for my sidekiq worker to find the file by its path, it can't because it doesn't exist. i've read that heroku's ephemeral file system deletes its files when things are reconfigured/servers are restarted, etc.

none of these things are happening, however and the file doesn't exist. so my theory is that the sidekiq worker is actually trying to open the path that gets passed to it on its own filesystem since it's a separate worker and that file doesn't exist. can someone confirm this? if that's the case, are the any alternate ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your worker is executed on another dyno than your web process, you are experiencing this issue because of dyno isolation. read more about this here:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#isolation-and-security

Although it is possible to run sidekiq workers and the web process on the same machine (maybe not on heroku, i am not sure about that), it is not advisable to design your system architecture like that.

If your application grows or experiences temporarily high loads, you may want to spread the load across multiple servers, and usually also run your workers on separate servers than your web process in order to not block the web process in case that your workers are keeping the server busy.

In all those cases you can never share data on the local filesystem between the web process and the worker.

I would recommend to consider directly uploading the file to S3 using https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload 
This also takes a lot of load off your web server

Comment: thanks. i will consider this, unfortunately it's an iphone app on the front end, but will look into a similar solution

Comment: In your scenario the solution might be even simpler. In your iOS App you can directly upload to S3 without having to care about not exposing any S3 credentials. I am not familiar with iOS development, but there are for you SDKs for direct S3 file storage.